# IE 11 freezes temporarily after Javascript Alert is accepted

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Asp.Net 4.5

Application has Textbox's with Minimum and Maximum values programmatically calculated on postback (server side), I call the js function from server code if it exceeds the limit. Works great in Chrome, FF. But in IE it freezes for approx. 2 minutes after user clicks [Ok] on the alert box. After about 2 minutes it allows the user to start making entries again. If I comment out the alert box then it works fine in IE. Any idea what would cause this only in IE?

Server side call to JS

```
If sender IsNot Nothing And TypeOf sender Is TextBox Then
   CType(sender, TextBox).Attributes.Add("onblur", "MinMaxBlurServer(this," & min & "," & max & ");")
End If
```

JavaScript Function

```
function MinMaxBlurServer(obj, hfmin, hfmax) {
   var txt = obj;
   var val = txt.value;
   var m = document.getElementById("MainContent_minmaxpanel");
   m.style.display = 'none';

   if (isNumber(val) == "") {
     if (val != "") {
        //alert("Invalid enery. You must enter a numeric value!");
        txt.value = "";
     }
   } else {
     if (isNumber(hfmin)) {
        if (parseFloat(val) < parseFloat(hfmin)) {
            //alert("Value cannot be less than " + hfmin + ".");
            txt.value = hfmin;
        }
     }
     if (isNumber(hfmax)) {
        if (parseFloat(val) > parseFloat(hfmax)) {
            //alert("Value cannot be greater than " + hfmax + ".");
            txt.value = hfmax;
        }
     }
   }
}
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: what is achieved by comparing boolean return value of `isNumber` function to an empty string? Simplify first line to: `var txt = obj;`

Comment: @Igor I made the edits to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by wrapping the alert box method in a window.setTimeout. See [link](http://tiku.io/questions/680773/javascript-alert-freezing-ios-browsers) for complete details. Example below.

```
window.setTimeout(function () { alert("Value cannot be less than " + hfmin + "."); }, 0);
```